# Text goes out of camera bounds

Tags: java, android, andengine

i am working on a quiz game in andengine in which there is a question and answers are bouncing 
but the problem is game is working fine but when is use PORTRAIT orentation, the question of my game goes out of camera bounds thus half question is only readable

how to set text to fit to camera width

```java
mBitmapFont=FontFactory.createFromAsset(this.getFontManager(),this.getTextureManager(),
200, 222, TextureOptions.BILINEAR,this.getAssets(), "Plok.ttf", 32, true, Color.WHITE);

question = new Text(10, 45, mBitmapFont, getString(R.string.question1), getVertexBufferObjectManager());
```

Comment: You have to focus with only one orientation in your application or game when you are using AndEnigne.

Answer (score 2):

You can scale text

```
if (question.getWidth() > CAMERA_WIDTH) {
    question.setScale(1/(question.getWidth()/CAMERA_WIDTH));
}
```

or "\n" in text for newline.

Comment: its not working frnd it only scaling text bt text is going out of camera width

Comment: what is your andengine version? my example work on GLES2-AE and text x position is center of screen

Answer (score 1):

@Alexey Thanks I solved the problem; your solution worked when I use your solution with this

```
    question = new Text(0, 0, mBitmapFont, getString(R.string.question10),
            getVertexBufferObjectManager());
   question.setScale(1/(question.getWidth()/CAMERA_WIDTH));
  question.setPosition((CAMERA_WIDTH - question.getWidth()) * 0.5f,5);
```

now text is inside camera boundaries.